# What style is the new Opera logo?

Tags: icon, style-identification

The new Opera logo looks really nice and so does the 2011 Office for Mac icons. What style are they?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeff, please take a look at our [style identification requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2931/52050) and make an [edit] to include the relevant info, thanks!

Comment: Please add those images to your question. As a new user (please do read the introductory [tour]), you may not be able to add them directly, but usually someone else then edits them into your post.

Comment: @Rad there aren't restrictions on images for new users on GD (or at least up to 3 images I think, maybe 2, can't remember)

Comment: Thanks for putting in the images. I couldn't put them in from my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of logo is generally referred to as '**ribbon style**' because of the way that the letters seem to be made from a folded or curved ribbon.

The examples that you have mentioned both use stylised versions of this approach, but the basic principle is the same. If you do a search for 'ribbon style logo' then you should find lots of examples and even a few tutorials.